# How to use bufferedwriter to write to cmd

Tags: java, cmd

I have already started `cmd.exe` using Java, but I still want to write more to `cmd.exe` without directly writing into cmd. Meaning that I want to use Java statements to write to the `cmd.exe`. I tried the following lines; however, they don't write anything to `cmd.exe`. How can I write the code so that it will write to `cmd.exe`.

```
BufferedReader one = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
BufferedWriter two = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
two.write("C:\Users\User\Desktop");
two.flush();
```

Comment: This is incredibly confusing. `I still want to write more to cmd.exe without directly writing into cmd`

Comment: `System.out.println("Whatever in string form");`

Comment: System.out.println(" ..."); only writes to the java console, not the cmd

Comment: p is probably the Process instance. He/she is probably trying to automate something in windows using Java. The best article I know about the pitfalls on this kind of thing is still this one http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html

Comment: if you want to automate things using the windows cmd, consider using libraries such as expect4j, expectj or expect-for-java. Don't reinvent the wheel